# Find out the users that has logged-in to TFS in last 6 months

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am trying to find out the users that has logged into TFS 2015 Update 3 in last 6 months.

Solution using C#/ REST API is good, if not available is there a way to generate the report using SQL.

I have followed this:[This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5cfd3628-eb1f-4f46-b15e-97dd90477d93/get-number-of-active-users-in-tfs-within-period-of-time?forum=tfsgeneral). I think the Query is not compatible with TFS 2015 Update 3 database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible if you don't clean up or archive the contents of the `tbl_command` in the TFS databases. By default these are cleaned up after 7 days (from the top of my head). The [limit can be changed by altering the job definition](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/granth/2010/11/11/tfs2010-update-activity-logging-cleanup-interval/) (which may need to be redone after each service pack installation).

Or you can setup a custom job that copies the contents of `tbl_command` to a custom table/database for future reference.

Which leaves you to see whether a user has made any work item changes or checked in code in he last 6 months, queued any builds, triggered any releases... Each uses a different API and a lot of these don't offer a easy query by user interface as far as I can know.

Comment: thanks for info, how do i collect the report who has logged in say last 7 days.

Comment: `select distinct identityname from tbl_command`, or something very close to it. (not behind a machine with the schema available)

Comment: Great answer @jessehouwing.  I had not considered this option. Easy and creative solution.

As for last 7 days please create a new StackOverflow question.
See SO Post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586124/how-to-get-list-of-current-active-tfs-users